# Windows Phone 8 Picture editing

Tags: windows-phone-8

I work with Windows Phone 8. I want to be able to take a button, tap it and load a picture from the phone into a window to edit it. Can someone please direct me to where I can find info on this or tutorials? I'm not asking someone to do this for me, just help on how to do it myself.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a bit too broad for StackOverflow, next time please try to focus on a smaller problem. "Windows Phone 8 Picture Editing" is too general.

But I know it is a hard topic to start on, and there are not many resources about it (especially compared to iOS). If you are not good with Windows Phone app development, I'd first recommend some easier examples.

Anyway, here is a simple app that demonstrates setting an image onto a view from a local file: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Loading_local_image_file_on_Tap_events_in_Windows_Phone

- If you want to choose an existing photo, it is even easier. You can
  follow the instructions at this link:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
- To take a photo, you can use the camera capture task, which is very
  similar to the photo picker. Here is how to use it:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
- If you need a more advanced/custom camera, you can implement your own
  camera. A relatively simpler example is here:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.photocamera%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
- If you trust yourself, a much advanced example is here (I also
  followed the same tutorial for creating an advanced photo filtering
  app):
- If that is too hard, you should definitely take a look at the Nokia
  Imaging SDK for Windows Phone 8. It has many built-in filters that
  anyone who is interested in making a photo editing app would like:
  http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/nokia_apis/imaging.xhtml
- If you still need more, or if you want something more lightweight and
  smaller than Nokia Imaging SDK, just look at
  WriteableBitmapExtensions that enables you to perform simple
  operations: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

When you are done with the actual image editing/programming, you should consider the user experience and total integration in more general.
To extend the phone to make your app a fully-featured editing app, head over here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Photo-Extensibility-Sample-db289044

This also explains the topic on extending the editing section in greater detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662932%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

I could write hundreds of lines of code directly here, but it wouldn't have meant anything. I hope these links help you (and many others) as a starting point for image editing on Windows Phone. But remember to ask more specific questions next time :)